# How to search index based values in table using angular 4?

Tags: angular, pipe, angularjs-filter, angular-pipe

I am using angular 4 and i have used array which contains list of values i need to search based on the index..i am getting error...How to search index based values?

**ang.html:**

```
<div class="col-md-6" >
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Category" />
            </div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive full-data-table">
    <thead>
    <tr><th S.No</th>
     <th>sName</th>
     <th>cName</th>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of data | category: searchText">
            <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
   </tbody>
```

**pipe.ts:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'category' })
export class CategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(categories: any, searchText: any): any {
    if(searchText == null) return categories;

    return categories.filter(function(category){
      return category.toLowerCase.indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase() != -1);
    })
  }
}
```

**error:**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Values:

```
[["Chrocin","paracetamal","combination name",200,10,18,"tablet",22,1],["Phar","chw","combination name",200,6,18,"tablet",3,2]]
```

Comment: Please update your code to "category.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase() != -1);"

Comment: i have done as you given code but i got error  "ERROR TypeError: category.toLowerCase is not a function" .....@ rohan kangale

Comment: i want know how to search  based on index...For ex "{{item[0]}}"....@ rohan kangale

Comment: toLowerCase() works only with string thats why you got the error

Comment: What is the data object? Is it list of objects or list of strings?

Comment: @AjithCsE can you post what does data contain

Comment: this is my values [["Chrocin","paracetamal","combination name",200,10,18,"tablet",22,1],["Phar","chw","combination name",200,6,18,"tablet",3,2]] in which i want search values based on index....@ Arun Kumaresh  and   Krishna Mohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not perform operation toLowerCase() on subarray. Your code is doing this:

```
[].toLowerCase()
```

You need to iterate through subarray of your array. And you can not toLowerCase() numbers, cast it to string. Something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'category' })
export class CategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(categories: any, searchText: any): any {
    if(searchText == null) return categories;

    //categories are [[]]
    return categories.filter(function(category){

      //category is []
      return category.filter(function(subCategory) {

        //subCategory is string that we compare with searchText
        return subCategory.toString().toLowerCase() == searchText.toLowerCase();
      });
    })
  }
}
```

If you wanna search by any field in subarray then you can do something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'category' })
export class CategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(categories: any, searchText: any): any {
    if(searchText == null || searchText == '') {
      return categories;
    } else {
      let filteredCategories = [];
      categories.filter(function(category){
        category.filter(function(subCategory) {
          if(subCategory.toString().toLowerCase() == searchText.toLowerCase()) {
            filteredCategories.push(category);
          }
        });
      });
      return filteredCategories;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is an example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/search-pipe

Comment: i got your point,how  to i search particular index value...for ex..{{item[0]}} i need!!

Comment: its ok fine  sir..but i want search by name...for ex..if i type any name that row should come....@ dev_in_progress

Comment: could  i have answer for the question??...@ dev_in_progress

Comment: Updated, check example and answer

Comment: thank u so much for your great time..its working fine.and one more query,its working only  when i give whole name...if i give singe or double  character its not working...pls give the solution.......@ dev_in_progress

Comment: for that case you can use  indexOf, there is a lot of examples on web so try to figure it out